# Replacing types in AST rascal

Tags: abstract-syntax-tree, rascal

I am trying to replace all types in an AST.
Analyzing Java language using m3 model; [definitions from here](https://github.com/usethesource/rascal/tree/master/src/org/rascalmpl/library/lang/java/m3)

If we take this code:

```
Int a = 1;
```

I am able to update the type of 1 to void for example.
But I am not able to change the type of the variable itself.

I've included some example lines.
Is someone able to point out the errors in the lines?

```
case \method(Type \return, str name, list[Declaration] parameters, list[Expression] exceptions)
    => \method(\int(), "funcHolder", parameters, exceptions)

case \type(Type \type) => \void()
case \type => \void
```

Comment: About which object language are we talking? Java? C#? C++? Which ADT definitions are you using for that Language? That should help in answering your question.

Comment: It's also important to distinguish between the syntactic representations of types in programs, such as "Int", and semantic attributes/decorations (sometimes also types) in the AST such as the type of "1". These different kinds have different representations, which are defined using different algebraic data-types usually. Pattern matching is sensitive to these differences. I'll be able to answer more concretely if you tell me which language you're manipulating.

Comment: I do think there is something incorrect in the cases, but am not sure. For instance, I'm guessing the last line inadvertently does not match anything since all constructors have parens, e.g., `\type()` versus just `\type`. Also, I'm not sure of the AST type definitions, but you have different "styles" in the rules, so you have both `\int()` as a type, but also a wrapper like `\type(Type t)`. So, echoing @jurgenv, it would help to see the AST definitions. It could be something just isn't matching, but the matcher allows you to get away with quite a bit without complaining.

Comment: @jurgenv The language im analyzing is java and I am using the built in m3 model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, excellent question. First your code and the errors it might have:

This looks good:

```
case \method(Type \return, str name, list[Declaration] parameters, list[Expression] exceptions)
    => \method(\int(), "funcHolder", parameters, exceptions)
```

The definition is: `data Declaration = \method(Type \return, str name, list[Declaration] parameters, list[Expression] exceptions, Statement impl);` (see [here](https://github.com/usethesource/rascal/blob/master/src/org/rascalmpl/library/lang/java/m3/AST.rsc#L26)), and your code follows exactly the definition. Every *abstract* method declaration in the ASTs you've parsed will match with this, since there is another `\method` declaration for methods with bodies with an additional argument.

It may be that you do not have abstract method bodies in your example code, in that case this does nothing.

A simpler version would also work fine:

```
case \method(_, _, parameters, exceptions) => \method(\int(), "funcHolder", parameters, exceptions)
```

The next one has issues:

```
case \type(Type \type) => \void()
```

Because `data Expression = \type(Type \type)`, that is an `Expression` and `data Type = \void()` that is a `Type` or `data TypeSymbol = \void()` it is a `TypeSymbol` the rewrite is not type-preserving and would do wrong things if the Rascal compiler would not detect this. Mostly it will probably not work for you because your example code does not contain this particular kind of expression. I suspect it might be the abstract notation for things such as `int.class` and `Integer.class`.

Then this one is "interesting":

```
case \type => \void()
```

In principle, if \type is not bound in the current scope, then this matches literally anything. But probably there is a function called \type or a variable or something somewhere, and thus this pattern tests for equality with that other thing in scope. Very nasty! It will not match with anything I would guess. BTW, we are planning a "Rascal Amendement Proposal" for a language change to avoid such accidental bindings of things in the scope of a pattern.

Later from the commments I learned that the goal was to replace all instances of a `Type` in the AST by `void()`, to help in clone detection modulo type names. This is done as follows:

```
case Type _ => \void()
```

We use a [TypedVariable] pattern, with the variable name `_` to match any node of algebraic type `Type` and forget about the binding. That node will then be replaced by `void()`.

My way of working in the absence of a content-assist tool for pattern matching is as follows:

1. find full one AST example of something you want to match, say `Int a = 1;`
2. copy it into the Rascal source file
3. remove the parts you want to abstract from by introducing variables or `_`
4. test on the original example
5. test on the rest of the system by printing out the `loc` that have matched and clicking on the locs to bring you to the code and see if it wasn't a false positive.

for example I want to rewrite `Int` to `void`, I find an example of `Int` in an AST and paste it:

```
visit (ast) {
   case simpleType(simpleName("Int")) => Type::\void()  // I added Type:: to be sure to disambiguate with TypeSymbol::void()
}
```

With some debugging code attached to print out all matches:

```
visit (ast) {
   case e:simpleType(simpleName("Int")) => Type::\void()  
     when bprintln("found a type at <e.src?|unknown:///|>");
}
```

Maybe you find out that that has way too many matches, and you have to become more specific, so let's only change declarations `Int _ = ....;`, we first take an example:

```
\variables(simpleType(simpleName("Int")), [...lots of stuff here...])
```

and then we simplify it:

```
\variables(simpleType(simpleName("Int")), names)
```

and then include it in the visit:

```
visit (ast) {
   case \variables(simpleType(simpleName("Int")), names) => \variables(Type::\void(), names) 
}
```

Final remark, as you can see you can nest patterns as deeply as you want, so any combination is fine. A "complex" example:

```
\variables(/"Int", names)
```

This pattern finds any variable declaration where the name "Int" is used somewhere as part of the type declaration. That's more loose than our original and might catch more than you bargained for. It's just to show what combinations you might want to do.

A final example of this: find all variable declarations with a type name which starts with "Int" but could end with anything else, like "Integer" or "IntFractal", etc:

```
\variables(simpleType(simpleName(/^Int/)), names)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So it is not possible to match all types using a type wildcard and we have to match all types individually? The reason I want to do this is for type 2 clone detection which has to ignore type differences.

Comment: O right! No that's really easy. Just write: 'Type _ => \void()' to match any type anywhere in the syntax tree and replace it by void, after this done detection is trivial. However, the .src fields make equal AST nodes unequal. So first visit all nodes to remove those fields, see Node.rsc for help. Then the relational operators can help or map operators to very quickly find all equal asts which are equal modulo type gaps and whitespace.